# Using TRUNCATE with EF 4.1 how to refresh object manager

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a windows service which uses EF 4.1. It reads data from a Web Service and inserts it into a few Cache table every 4 hours or so. Around 3k rows av.

I have it Deleting all rows using EF 4.1 then Adding all rows in a std EF 4.1 way. works fine i.e.

```
....
foreach (var entityI in entityList)
{
    _dbContext.GetDbSet<T>().Remove(entityI);
}
SaveChanges();

....
foreach (var entityI in entityList)
{
    _dbContext.GetDbSet<T>().Add(entityI);  
}
SaveChanges();
```

What I'm trying to do is use TRUNCATE TABLE instead of delete but when I do this, the TRUNCATE TABLE works perfectly but the Add rows fails saying the object manager is out of step.

```
_dbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " + entityName);
```

The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

How do I tell the EF object manager that I've truncated all rows in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to detach all corresponding entities from the ObjectStateManager. Then the entities would be eligble for garbage collection, and finally removed.

```
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext;
var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;

var entries = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified);

foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    objectContext.Detach(entry);
}
```

Comment: Had similar thought. No entries coming back from GetObjectStateEntries though I can find them using GetObjectByKey. But then can't Detach.

Comment: Finally got rows coming back but now saying the object cannot be detached because it's not attached. To Attach I need an IEntityWithKey.

Comment: Can you try doing a objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, objectContext.<YourType>) after doing the truncate command? That should reload entities from the datastore, which should be empty.

Comment: Tried that : System.InvalidOperationException: The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager.